# Discord.js How do we get the id of a category from CategoryChannel (json)

Tags: node.js, json, discord.js

This is for a discord bot in javascript.

In one of my personnal project i'm looking to get an id of a category i create to create after that a channel in this particular category.

```
const category = message.guild.channels.create('Horobot', {
    type: 'category',
    })
    .then((category) => {
        console.log(category)
    })
```

this is what i get from categorychannel the json file:

[image]

To get to the id i've done this: `const categoryId = CategoryChannel['id']`

But it says the constant is undefined.

Comment: Try `category.id`.

Comment: I recommend learning JS objects and collections. This is a core JavaScript concept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a category and add a channel to it easily.
Just set the parent after the category has been created.

```js
const category = message.guild.channels.create('Horobot', { type: 'category' });
message.guild.channels.create('Channel1', {
    parent: category,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If I read this right, you want to be able to create a channel within that category, correct?

I found this code in another post which, if you have the category already created, it should be able to create the channel.
So, first off, after the message event is triggered, we should try to create the channel, and specify the category we want it to create the channel in:

```
message.guild.createChannel("NAME", "text")
  .then(channel => {
    let category = message.guild.channels.cache.find(c => c.name === "Name of the category" && c.type === "category");
```

To make sure nothing goes wrong, we make an instance where, if the category is missing, it does not execute the command, so:

```
    if (!category) return console.log("Category channel does not exist");
    channel.setParent(category.id);
```

And boom, the channel should be created.

Or if you only want the ID:

```
let category = message.guild.channels.cache.find(c => c.name === "Category name" && c.type === "category");
```

And use `category.id` to receive the ID.
I am really new, so I hope this helps :)
PS: The post was really outdated, so I am sorry if I forgot to update something...